# Is memory used by an object's declared, but undefined member?

Tags: actionscript-3

If my class has declared a

`private var _iDontGetDefined:EnormousObject;`

but never creates anything to be stored there, does this impact performance or use a significant amount of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such declaration will not affect performance and will have almost no impact on memory footprint.

If you want to maintain a lot of similar and optional values, you may consider using a Dictionary.

Comment: I was going to comment, but you pretty much summed it up. I will add this - the declaration of a class variable should be separate from its assignment. Assignment should go in the constructor or set functions, so @Pup, you're doing it right.